Why did Yaakov place stones around his head
I am looking for a summary of explanations for why Yaakov placed stones (Bereishit 28:11) around ('near' or 'at') his head that isn't Rashi's explanation of protection against animals.

Where do you get that he took more than one stone (v. 11 "ויקח מאבני המקום", and v. 18 "ויקח את האבן אשר שם מראשתיו"), or that he put it/them around his head? (Are picking and choosing which of Rashi's explanations you accept?)

@TamirEvan the pasuk seems clear enough.

@bondok The pasuk (28:11) is not so clear: (1) "ויקח מאבני המקום" could mean "ויקח [אבן] מאבני המקום" or "ויקח [אבנים] מאבני המקום". A later pasuk (v. 18) strongly implies (if not outright states) that it was a single stone that Yaakov took, "ויקח את האבן אשר שם מראשתיו". Rashi says he took more than one stone (in v. 11), and by the time he got up in the morning, they became one stone...

@bondok ...(2) Most of the 13 translations [currently] offered by Sefaria translate 'מראשתיו' as either 'at his head' or 'under his head'. All of the four I found that translate it as 'around his head/body' here in v. 11, translate it as "at/under his head" in v. 18. That strongly suggests that those 4 deviated from the clear understanding in v.11, to be in line with Rashi.

@TamirEvan thank you for this clarification. I think it helps the question. I've made an edit.

Perhaps, you are looking for Bereshis Rabba 68:11,

“He took from the stones of the place” (Genesis 28:11) – Rabbi Yehuda, Rabbi Neḥemya, and the Rabbis argue:

Rabbi Yehuda said: He took twelve stones. So, the Holy One blessed be He decreed that he would produce twelve tribes. He [Jacob] said: ‘Abraham did not produce them, Isaac did not produce them, I, if these twelve stones join with one another, I know that I will produce twelve tribes.’ When the twelve stones joined together one to another, he knew that he would produce twelve tribes.

Rabbi Neḥemya said: He took three stones. He said: ‘Abraham, the Holy One blessed be He designated His name upon him; Isaac, the Holy One blessed be He designated His name upon him; I, if these three stones join with one another, I know that He will designate His name upon me.’ When the three stones joined with one another, he knew that the Holy One blessed be He would designate His name upon him.

The Rabbis said: The minimum number of “stones” is two. Abraham, waste emerged from him – Ishmael and all the sons of Ketura. Isaac, Esau and all his chieftains emerged [from him]. I, if these two stones join with one another, I will know that waste will not emerge from me.

Rabbi Levi and Rabbi Elazar said in the name of Rabbi Yosei bar Zimra: He made them in the shape of a roof gutter and placed it beneath his head because he feared the beasts.


Rabbi Berekhya and Rabbi Levi said in the name of Rabbi Ḥama bar Ḥanina (explain why the stones joined even according to Rabbi Levi and Rabbi Elazar): It is written: “For, behold, the Lord emerges from His place, and will descend and tread on the heights of the earth. [The mountains will melt under Him, and the valleys will burst like wax before the fire, like waters poured down a slope]” (Micah 1:3–4). (Even in a place where God only ‘passes through,’ valleys burst like wax.) All the more so for one in a place where the Holy One blessed be He has revealed Himself. (The stones melt and are joined together in a place where God's presence is not transient.)

There is also a less cheerful Bereshis Rabba 68:13


Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi interpreted the verse regarding the exile. “Jacob departed [vayetze] from Beersheba” (Genesis 28:10) – just as it says: “Send them from My presence, and let them go [veyetze’u]” (Jeremiah 15:1). “And went to Ḥaran” (Genesis 28:10) – just as it says: “With which the Lord has tormented me on the day of His enflamed wrath [ḥaron apo]” (Lamentations 1:12).  “He encountered the place” (Genesis 28:11) – “until there is no more place” (Isaiah 5:8). “And stayed the night there because the sun had set” (Genesis 28:11) – “the one who bore seven is miserable…[her sun set while still day]” (Jeremiah 15:9). “He took from the stones from the place” (Genesis 28:11) – “The sacred stones are spilled at the head of every street” (Lamentations 4:1). “Which he placed beneath his head” (Genesis 28:11) – “[splendor] has come down from your heads” (Jeremiah 13:18). “And lay in that place” (Genesis 28:11) – “we will lie in our shame, and our humiliation will cover us” (Jeremiah 3:25).


Chizkuni states that the stones came from the altar on which his father Yitzchak was sacrificed.

It is interesting to me, that where as Rashi s.v. "וישם מראשותיו" (and the OP) says Yaakov arranged the stones  "around his head" ("סביב לראשו"), Rabbi Levi and Rabbi Elazar, in the name of Rabbi Yosei bar Zimra, are quoted by Bereshis Rabba as saying that he placed them (as a roof gutter) "beneath his head" ("תחת ראשו").
